# how can set alarm icon for login password?

Tags: keyboard, login, language-support

i have Ubuntu 18.04.
i use multi language in my system.
i want to that when i want login account in Ubuntu the language of keyboard system is Suggest with icon that have tow word of language keyboard(example:en,fa,..).
for example : when we want to login account in  Ubuntu if caps lock key is turn or on, its alarm with  icon dangerous suggest to user.
my goal of this setting system is Awareness user for Type of language
system keyboard to login password. 
can i do this setting in Ubuntu?